# Is there an IE alternative for selection.modify()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have some code that relies on [selection.modify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.modify) which only works on Firefox and Chrome.  Does anyone know of a workaround, alternate method or polyfill available for Internet Explorer?  Only needs to be supported on IE 9+

Comment: Have you tried https://code.google.com/p/rangy/ ?

Comment: No I haven't but a quick review of it shows that it doesn't offer any selection modification methods.  Probably because the cross-browser requirement limits them to LCD features.

Comment: Yeah, on second thought, it doesn't implement anything close to `selection.modify()`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @jibsales comment: Now Rangy does have a [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) that allows functionality similar, or equivalent to, `selection.modify()`.